# Find the constant *c* so that p(x) satisfies the condition of being a pmf of one random variable X.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation

Find the constant *c* so that p(x) satisfies the condition of being a pmf of one random variable X.

p(x) = $c\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x$ , x = 1, 2, 3, ... , zero elsewhere.

The way I approached this problem is the following.

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:c\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=1$

I am just confused how to solve for c from that equation.

If this is the right approach, please help me figure out how to solve for c. If it is not the right approach, what is the right approach?

Comment: "probability density function" (pdf) is a more usual term than "probability mass function" (pmf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The expression $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:c\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=1$ can be re-written as:

$$c\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=1$$

You should be able to compute $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$. If you do not know how to sum the infinite series then look up [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) on wikipedia for details as to how to find the sum. Once you know the value of the infinite series just solve for $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want $p(x)$ to be a *Probability Mass Function*, your approach is correct, since for any such function $f_X:A\to[0,1], X:S\to A\subseteq\mathbb R$, it is :

$$\sum _{x\in A}f_X(x)=1$$

For your particular exercise, as you've taken correctly that condition, you can continue as :

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:c\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=1 \Leftrightarrow c\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=1 \Leftrightarrow 2c = 1 \Leftrightarrow c= \frac{1}{2}$$

In the case you're not sure on how to sum the particular infinite series, check up in your textbook/internet foer *Geometric Series* and such summations.

Comment: how would i do it for f(x) = (1-c)*c^x where x = 0, 1, 2, 3, .....